# How to delete an element by specific value in an array in MongoDB object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

I can't seem to find my way to an element by specific value in an array. I tried something like this, but it is not working for me sadly:

```
const item_delete = Number(args[0])

const shopData = await shopSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
            guildID: message.guild.id
        },
        {$pull:
            {items: 
                {itemID: item_delete
                    }
                }
            })
```

I also tried findoneanddelete but that just removes the whole thing by GuildID. Please have a look on screenshot. [MongoDB database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YtjD.png)
Or a code how the database looks:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60ef47b6d18d063248a41fdb"),
    "guildID" : "859427262713692220",
    "__v" : 0,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "itemID" : "1",
            "item" : "Nazwa",
            "price" : "1000",
            "description" : "Opis",
            "eligible" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "3",
            "item" : "nazwa itemu",
            "price" : "500",
            "description" : "opis eoeoeoeoeo",
            "eligible" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which element do you like to remove? The first one?

Comment: I want to delete an element by itemID. I choose an ItemID in 
const item_delete = Number(args[0])

I want to choose it with a command. !delitem ItemID

Comment: Everything is ready except the fact that I don't know how to find my way to this specific element with this specific ItemID and remove it. I want it to look through all elements and remove the one I want

Comment: The syntax of your update looks correct. You need to make sure the input values are correct. What are the values of `message.guild.id` and `item_delete`?

Comment: This is not discord.js related, but node.js - please remove the discord.js tag

Comment: prasad_ - message.guild.id is the GuildID  in which someone does the command so I can find the correct one in the database. item_delete is the value someone types in after the command. I want to type item_delete  and search for the correct ItemID in the database and remove the element. !itemdel <ItemID - item_delete>